# in a gnuplot script how to go access the range

Tags: gnuplot

I call a function in a gnuplot session, and would like to know the ranges and also if a logscale is used inside this function. How to do that ?
Thank you

```
gnuplot> load 'myfunction.gnu'
```

the file `myfunction.gnu`:

```
if "logscale" {do this};else {do that}
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution could be as follows. Let's say that the main script looks like:

```
set logscale x
set xr [10:100]

load 'my_function.gpl'
```

Then in `my_function.gpl`, you could do:

```
set terminal push
set terminal unknown
plot 1
isLogScale = (GPVAL_X_LOG > 0)?1:0
xMin = GPVAL_X_MIN
xMax = GPVAL_X_MAX
set terminal pop

if(isLogScale){
    print "logscale"
}else{
    print "..."
}
```

The idea is to:

1. save the current terminal with `set terminal push`
2. set a "fake" terminal with `set terminal unknown`
3. generate a plot into this terminal (nothing is plotted) in order to force Gnuplot to initialize its internal variables used in the lines below
4. check the log scaling using `GPVAL_X_LOG` (equal to zero if `logscale` hasn't been set) and ranges with `GPVAL_X_MIN`, `GPVAL_X_MAX`.
5. revert the terminal settings with `set terminal pop`
6. perform some action using this information

However, the catch is that although `set logscale x` sets `GPVAL_X_LOG` by default to 10, `unset logscale` does not revert it back to zero, so if one used `set logscale x;unset logscale`, the code snippet above would not handle this correctly...

In my opinion, a better solution would be to introduce a custom variable in the main script as:

```
useLogScale = 1

if(useLogScale){
    set logscale x
}

set xr [10:100]

load 'my_function.gpl'
```

then the variable `useLogScale` is also directly available in `my_function.gpl`.